# Where Can I Find Stardrops?

Tags: ni-no-kuni-wrath-of-the-white-witch

As the title says, where can I find **Stardrops**?

I'm having no trouble with drops / stealing for Planetdrops, Moondrops, and Sundrops, but I haven't had any luck with Stardrops.  And, as it turns out, it seems that most of the familiars I'm using need Stardrops for the metamorphosis.

Comment: I believe I read in the Wizard's Companion that they take star crystals to make. However, I'm not sure where to get those. I've heard they're in Billy Goat's Bluff, from foraging or ThunderByrdes, but I can't confirm it just yet.

Comment: I've found the Valley of Tears to be the best place to farm them. The Deep Fries in Old Smokey and the Wishing Whambats on Teeheeti Island drop them as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a list of creatures, and their habitats, that possess Stardrops:

- Bighorn - Skull Mountain
- Gruffian - Nevermore
- Tadabout - The Winter Isles
- Deecee - Sea - The Spring Realm
- Wishing Whambat - Teeheeti
- Horrid Floret - The Spring Isles
- Deep Fry - Old Smoky
- Megalith - The Vault of Tears
- Shonky-Honker - Castaway Coast
- Bone Ranger - Ghostly Gorge
- Zombo - The Tombstone Trail

Answer (score 0):

You can make jumbo star drops if you have 3 star crystals and 1 star drop but on how to get them I just realized this fact so I had a bunch of them, you also need the cauldron, I wish I could help out more